# linq to sql order by

Tags: linq-to-sql, nested, sql-order-by

How to order result by nested table column like

```
FROM a IN Repository
FROM b IN a.Users
ORDERBY b.Name
SELECT a
```

But it does not work, i want to select all in 'a' table whitch is order by Name column in relation table 'b', how can I?
Thanks.

**UPD: I'm very sorry. My fault is my thoughtlessness. Probably, i didn't notice the post processing the list of elements from result where it ordered again. Thanks for all guys!**

Comment: Is this really linq-to-sql? Where is the datacontext in that case? Or is it linq-to-objects?

Comment: what is a circuit matter in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but I would do this

```
var query = from ab in
              (from a in Repository
              select new
              {
                A = a,
                B = a.Users.OrderBy(u => u.Name).FirstOrDefault()
              })
            orderby ab.B.Name
            select ab.A;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a relation between the tables? Do you have navigation properties? In that case, use:

```
from a in repository.a
orderby a.Users.Name
select a;
```

Comment: hah, i't will be very easy. You can't use column in b table from a because this is collection...
and i haven't navigation properties

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a property to an partial class, and then use the other property instead.

```
public partial class Repository
{
    public IOrderedEnumerable<User> OrderedUser
    {
        get
        {
            return this._User.OrderByDescending(u => u.Name);
        }
    }
}
```